# Userfriendly forms for links in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a form with the following behavior:

1. Clicking it when it's empty opens the dialogue window of inserting a hyperlink
2. Clicking it when there's a hyperlink opens the hyperlink
3. Clicking a nearby "Clear" button clears the form deleting the hyperlink (if present)

I'm currently stuck with step 2. The code for hyperlink insertion window is this one:

```
Private Sub PSIC_Click()
Me.[PSIC].SetFocus
On Error GoTo browse_stop
RunCommand acCmdInsertHyperlink
browse_stop:
End Sub
```

When I try to apply different *if then* variations it doesn't work as expected. Either I fail in properly applying *if then* or in determining that the form is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnClick()` event of your hyperlink textbox would be:

```
Private Sub PSIC_Click()
On Error GoTo browse_stop
If ISNULL(Me!PSIC) Then
  RunCommand acCmdInsertHyperlink
End If
browse_stop:
End Sub
```

I removed `SetFocus` because clicking on the textbox should automatically set the focus, but if you need it there for some other reason it wasn't really hurting anything.

The "Clear form" command button's `OnClick()` event would be:

```
Private Sub cmdClearForm_Click()
Me!PSIC = NULL
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine except for one issue. If a link is present and I click it then it opens twice. There was no such problem with the old entry fields. I have no idea what causes such behavior.

Comment: @wintermute Is the hyperlink property of your text box blank? It should be, but if it is and is still opening twice set a breakpoint on the `FollowHyperlink` line and then click the hyperlink in form view. Does it open once before the break?

Comment: @wintermute also, the `True` argument opens a new browser window, so you might try setting to `false` and see how it behaves.

Comment: Looks like it opens the link for the second time after the function (I might use wrong terms here) ends. So first time the link is opened by `FollowHyperlink` and the second time it's opened by default hyperlink clicking handler. Changing `True` to `False` doesn't help. I will try to remove `FollowHyperlink` and see if it works.

Comment: @wintermute I've edited my code to allow the handler to direct the hyperlink by default.

Comment: Thank you! I've come to the same solution and it works like a charm. Well, except for the fact that the cleared field doesn't work until I save the record, but I think I will add saving to the clearing button as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To open a hyperlink from a form in MS Access:

In Design View make sure that the hyperlink is in its own text box and then go to the 'property sheet' then half way down you should see the option for Hyperlink Address. In here add the address of the hyperlink.

If you want to click on an image and have it open a hyperlink then right-click on the image go to hyperlink.